# Specific string generation in python of 5 alphabets followed by 4 numbers. example ABCDE1234

Tags: python-3.x, string, random, alphanumeric

I have used the following code but not getting  the desired output. please help me.

"{}{}{}".format((random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase)for i in range(5)), random.randint(1000,9999))

Comment: What happens when you run it?  You say you don't get the desired output, but what do you get?

Comment: You should take a look at this [(How to ask good question)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).Your question is not clear.

Comment: I was getting no output. It was not showing error but no output was coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why it doesn't work, but I managed to get it to print the desired result using this code:

```
x = []
y = ""
for i in range(5):
    x += random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase)

x += str(random.randint(1000,9999))
    

print (y.join(x))
```

My guess is that it's because you're trying to add a list (your method of string generation produces a list of string characters) and an integer (randint produces an integer) to a string.

Comment: can we write it in single line? just a thought

Comment: Possibly, but you'll need a better coder than me :P I always find it best to keep things nice and separate anyway to be honest. That way things are easier to understand when you need to go back and fix the inevitable bugs that show up later.